# Image1.Imageurl not working in Chrome

Tags: vb.net

I need help with Image1.Imageurl, my code only displays image in IE only but not in Chrome. Basically I created generic handler to get the image from database and pass it to Image controller. Please advise how do I can make it work in Chrome and IE. Below is my Code, Thank you.

```
    Dim fileName As String = context.Request.QueryString("fn")

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLConnection").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select binary from ImageProcess where fileName = '" & fileName & "'", con)

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()

    Dim b64 As String = dr(0).ToString.Replace(" ", "+")
    Dim b() As Byte

    b = Convert.FromBase64String(b64)

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/tiff"
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(b)
    con.Close()
    context.Response.[End]()
```